# 3 divs, side by side, center one horizontally aligned, other occupying remaining space and NOT behind center div

Tags: css, html

I've been looking in forums and I can't find a similar problem. Seemed to me that a simple `overflow:hidden` could fix this problem, but it isn't working...

I've created an example here:
http://www.estrelasustentavel.pt/demo

So, what it would like is to have the "side" `divs` (left and right) to occupy all space left by the center div (horizontally aligned). The size of the center div could have a fixed width, but preferably not....

the problem is that I don't want the side `divs` to stay behind the center div, because I'm going to make an "over" action of these images to have a bit of transparency. And the background image (the forest) should be visible, so the side `divs` shouldn't take any space behind the center div.

Comment: look at [`display: flex`](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the CSS table layout to achieve that.

in this demo, the second div takes exactly the space he needs, and the first and third div occupy the rest.

that also can be achieved by using `display: flex`, but currently, the CSS table layout have a better browser support (IE8+)

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/eQwCn/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="Row">
    <div class="Stretch">First</div>
    <div class="Content">second will always occupy as much as he can</div>
    <div class="Stretch">Third</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.Row
{
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}

.Row > div
{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #e5b9b9;
}
.Content
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.Stretch
{
    width: 50%;
}
```

In the solution I use `nowarp` on the second div,
so if you have a lot of text that needs to be broken to lines, put `</br>` tags.

Comment: OK avrahamcool, your solution seems pretty good. I updated my example to your code. However I had to apply a fixed width to the UL inside the center DIV to have a proper width on that DIV. What's the purpose of "nowrap" property? Doesn't seem to have any effect... Any suggestion on how to not force width to center DIV elements?

Comment: can you post that part of HTML & CSS in a fiddle? it will be easier to play with and find you a good solution.

Comment: sure! thanks for your attention! note that if the width of the UL is removed, the cell loses its format... http://jsfiddle.net/eQwCn/13/

Comment: use `inline-block` instead of `float` for the `li`. also: remove the default padding from the `ul` & `li` - check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/eQwCn/14/)

Comment: OK, avrahamcool. perfect solution for the problem. thank you so much for your help.